# cloud-init images are minimal. Is there any full server cloud-init image matched what we get with standard Ubuntu ISO installation?

Tags: cloud-init

I created a Proxmox cloud-init image and I am noticing the image is locked down and minimal.

Is there any full server cloud-init image matched what we get with standard Ubuntu ISO installation?

**Update 1**

I am taking my images here:

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/

Comment: Thank you for help. I updated my question where I am taking my images. So the idea is to have the image as minimal as possible, and I need to install extend it using the cloud-init config file? If yes, to my understanding Proxmox  provides minimal ability to configure cloud-init.

Comment: I don't understand why you say your Ubuntu Server cloud image is "locked down and minimal." What were you expecting? Did you follow the instructions?

Comment: Ok, I am new to cloud-init trying to understand it. For example, the image I built does not allow password ssh, only ssh key. To my understanding, Proxmox ability to customize a cloud init image is limited. Am I correct?

I think my problem is more with Proxmox limited ability to apply a cloud init configuration. 

Should I post this to a Proxmox forum?

Comment: Do you know a good place to post Proxmox questions? I can't find a way to supply my cloud-init configuration to Proxmox cloud init VM templates.

Comment: There are two ways to customize an Ubuntu Server cloud image: 1) Login to the "Ubuntu" username. 2) Use a cloud-init YAML file. Hosts (including Proxmox) do not directly customize Ubuntu Server cloud images, though Proxmox prefers to use their own templates to retain the customized systems. An example is at https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Cloud-Init_Support